# Angular database order by

Tags: html, angular, sql-order-by, mean, web-frontend

So I'm creating a blog for my website. Database is working just fine but the order of my posts aren't in the right way. Top is the oldest and I want the newest in the top. Since Im using MEAN/Angular I'm having hard time to use any JavaScript in my code. Anyone can help me to order the database by the new just using front-end code without JavaScript?

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let b of allBlogs">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="post-preview" class="animated zoomIn delay-2s">
              
                <h2 class="post-title" style="margin: 30px; font-size:30px;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace">
                        {{b.title}}
                </h2>
                <h5 class="post-subtitle" style="margin: 30px; font-size:12px;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace">
                       Category:  {{b.category}}
                </h5>
                <h4 class="post-subtitle" style="margin: 30px; font-size:15px;font-weight: normal; text-align: justify; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace">
                        {{b.content}}
                </h4>

              <p class="post-meta" style="margin: 30px; font-size:12px;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace">Posted by Tico
                
                on {{b.created_at}}</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do mean with "just using frontend code?". Javascript can be a frontend code

Comment: You're right, I was saying that some code I could use in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could write your own orderBy pipe, however [this](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) is what Angular has to say about that:

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists.
>   Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy.
>   There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer **such pipes because they
>   perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification.** Both filter and
>   orderBy require parameters that reference object properties.
>   Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change-detection cycle.
>
> **Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations.** The user
>   experience can degrade severely for even moderate-sized lists when
>   Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second. filter and
>   orderBy have often been abused in AngularJS apps, leading to
>   complaints that Angular itself is slow. That charge is fair in the
>   indirect sense that AngularJS prepared this performance trap by
>   offering filter and orderBy in the first place.

What I would recommend is to use [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in your service which is fetching the data from you db. This way, you can avoid some of the performance overheads mentioned above.

```
this.httpClient.get("my/server/address").subscribe((data) => { 
    data.sort((a, b) => { 
        return a.date < b.date ? 1 : -1; // not sure if the 1's should swap here
    });
});
```